# Will I run into trouble with this Git rebase workflow?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've just learned about rebase, and I've been [strongly warned](http://learn.github.com/p/rebasing.html#the_perils_of_rebasing) not to rebase commits after they have been pushed to a remote. I want to make sure I'm not going to explode my repository

#### Example commit history

```
foo               W---X---Y  
                 /         \
master  A---B---C---D---E---Z---F---G
```

- Here, all commits on the master branch will likely have been pushed to origin/master.
- `Z` is an automatic commit made by git-merge by merging the completed foo branch (Y) with the current master (E).
- Since the completion of the foo module, master has made some updates (F and G).

---

### Here's how I'd like to use rebase.

It's time to make some updates on the foo branch, but it's out of sync with the master branch.

1. Is it ok to simply `git rebase master` to include F and G commits on the latest foo branch?
2. Can you modify my diagram to show me what my commit history will look like afterward?

Comment: Also note that you don't always want the contents of master in a topic branch. It's very nice if you can completely independently develop a feature/bugfix on its own branch, then merge it once into whatever branches (master, maintenance, next version...) need it, without picking up anything extraneous.

Answer (score 2):

1. Hypothetically, yes, it is okay to do because git will detect that `foo` has already merged to master and will fast-forward `foo` to the state `master` is in. This is the same thing that `git merge master` would do, and also means that, quite simply, foo is the same thing as master.

   Knowing that, however, I would just use `git merge` here, since that makes more logical sense to me (you use merge to do fast-forwards, it even has an `--ff-only` flag if you want to make sure you're not doing a real merge). The time to use rebase is when you're working on `foo` and have several commits there (and haven't pushed it) and someone has committed to master. Rebase will bring your branch up to date without doing a merge commit.
2. I could, but it would be the same diagram, but with `foo` now pointing to master, or more accurately, commit `G`. No new commits are created, so the repository would stay the same with the exception of moving what  `foo` references.

PS. I tested this locally on a fake repository to make sure, since using a rebase in this scenario was not something I had tried before.

Comment: +1 wuputah, thanks. I'm going to do some more testing with rebase and merge. If this ends up working, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @macek: I'd amend the advice to use merge: use the command you actually mean. In this case, they're both going to fast forward, but that's not always the case. So, if you are on one branch and know that you want to incorporate all the content of another branch, use merge. Only use rebase if you actually believe you want to transplant a branch.